# Removing text using a button swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have made an app and just wondered if the user could click the save button and then there text they typed into a textfield would be deleted! I have seen this on many different apps and wondered how I could do it!

Thanks, 
AppSwiftGB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to have a reference to the `UITextField` either via an `IBOutlet` through the storyboard or through a class variable that you have a reference too.

Once the done button is pressed you can then set the text inside of the `UITextField` to either nil or empty.

```
@interface ViewController()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    self.textField.text = nil;
}

@end
```

Above is how you can do it if you use an `IBOutlet` hooked up through the Storyboard.

Below is the swift equivalent

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField?

    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.textField?.text = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this in objective-c because swift doesn't read this, and if so I am programming in swift!